# LuaTeX issue with space in path?

Tags: luatex, windows

Using TeXnicCenter on Windows 7 I stumbled over an issue with LuaTeX from TeXLive 2015 where certain documents would not compile. I tried different things and found a common theme: if there is a space in a directory name LuaTeX trips and I don't really now how to work around it.

```
lualatex "C:\temp\abc,def\test.tex"

This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.80.0 (TeX Live 2015/W32TeX) (rev 5238)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
(c:/temp/abc,def/test.tex
LaTeX2e <2015/01/01> 
[...]
```

but with a directory name with a space it suddenly fails:

```
lualatex "C:\temp\abc, def\test.tex"

This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.80.0 (TeX Live 2015/W32TeX) (rev 5238)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
! Undefined control sequence.
<*> "C:\temp
         \abc, def\test.tex"
?
```

I thought this should work because the path is in quotes but this does not seem to be enough. 
How do I have to setup the command for LuaTeX so that this works?

Comment: Which TeX distribution (and which vintage) is installed on your system? The reason I ask is that I can't replicate the error you say you're getting when running lualatex of MikTeX 2.9 on a tex file stored in `c:\temp\abc, def\ `.

Comment: @Mico it's TeX Live 2015/W32TeX :-)

Comment: Normally you need to use `/` not `\ ` in file paths for tex (although on the command line the dos convention sometimes works) you could try `/temp/abc....`  certainly you will not get undefined command `\temp` error then. Note it is almost always better to cd to that folder then use `lualatex test` as otherwise aux and other file get written in (typically) the wrong place.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Yes, and if I type the path by hand this would work. Unfortunately TeXnicCenter uses ´\´ by default and this is not configurable by the user. Mico's comment indicates that this is a TeXLive specific bug, so maybe some configuration setting can be used to allow backshlashes and spaces in paths in TeXLive as well.

Comment: To ascertain whether this is a TeXLive or a TeXnicCenter bug, can you run the commands from a command prompt as well as from within TeXnicCenter? Do both approaches fail, or just one?

Comment: @Mico: I tested this on the command line. It is not tied to TeXnicCenter in any other way than that TeXnicCenter uses backslashes when building the command to hand to LuaTeX.

Comment: Why does TeXniccenter insert the full path instead of simply calling `lualatex test`?

Comment: Alexander I wouldn't call it a bug, the command line is accessed as _tex_ commands you can do `pdflatex '\def\foo{xxx} \input myfile'`  the fact that a simple file name is implictly input is a special case. So the expected behaviour of `\temp` on the command line is to execute the command `\temp`. miktex may try a bit harder to guess when a string is a windows path, but to be honest I'm surprised that the path works on any implementation with or without a space.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Imho the behaviour is odd. `lualatex "C:\some\full\path\test"` works fine, `lualatex "C:\some path with space\test"` and `lualatex path\test` fails at the backslash (in texlive). It is not very consequent.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer actually I'm out of time to look now but I'm not sure if this is in luatex binary or in the lua callback used to quote jobname, something to check....

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Miktex handles all the cases fine but I don't know if it has already the same ini as texlive - and I don't have the time now to check (I also don't find it very important as I never use spaces and never call lualatex from another directory.